# Jupyter notebook Toolbar display issue

Tags: toolbar, jupyter

My OS is Win10,python version is 3.6/3.5.
I installed jupyternotebook by 'pip install jupyter notebook',
It showed the package is successfully installed.
But when I click the 'View/Toggle toolbar' button,
nothing happened. The toolbar does not show up.

[image: image description]

I don't get it. I reinstalled jupyter for several times, just didn't work.
Can anyone help me to get through this! many thanks.

Comment: This is not a programming question. This is not the right place to ask this question. Please contact jupyter developers

Comment: What browser are you using? Try different browsers to see if it is particular to one browser.